# React Material Design Icon hover not working correctly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm using mdi-react icons and the hovering doesnt work well. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt.

```
import MagnifyPlusOutline from "mdi-react/MagnifyPlusOutlineIcon";
import MagnifyMinusOutline from "mdi-react/MagnifyMinusOutlineIcon";
import DoubleDownChevron from "mdi-react/ChevronDoubleDownIcon";
import DoubleUpChevron from "mdi-react/ChevronDoubleUpIcon";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DoubleUpChevron className="viewIcon" size={38} />
      <DoubleDownChevron className="viewIcon" size={38} />
      <MagnifyPlusOutline className="viewIcon" size={32} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS

```
.viewIcon :hover {
  color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can see on the sandbox, if you hover sometimes it works, but sometimes the cursor doesnt become a pointer,even if I'm right over the icon

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-leftpad-j2tj9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rookie css mistake I guess, Try removing the extra space before `:hover`

```
.viewIcon:hover {
  color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Worked thanks! do you know the reason why?

Comment: That's the proper syntax, html css do not provide errors but just messes with the page when there is a problem.

p.s do mark it as the answer, increases my reputation ;)